# Firebase function for nodemailer deployed but no logs and not working correctly with database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I have setup a firebase-function with nodemailer to grab the input from my 
firebase-database connected to my contact form and email it to my email.

I have successfully deployed the function and can see the function showing up in my firebase console, however i do not receive any errors in the console nor see any logs or information in the function section of the console. And it just simply doesn't work right now.

This is the first time i am doing this, and i have looked at almost all other similar questions on SO but none of them have given me any clues as to what i am doing wrong.

This is my functions package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.3.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

and this is the index.js code inside the functions-folder:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");


const gmailEmail = "k****l@gmail.com";
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.pass;

admin.initializeApp();


var goMail = function(message) {

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: gmailEmail,
      pass: gmailPassword
    }
  });


  const mailOptions = {
    from: gmailEmail, // sender address
    to: "****l@gmail.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "!", // Subject line
    text: "!" + message, // plain text body
    html: "!" + message // html body
  };


  const getDeliveryStatus = function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);

  };


  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, getDeliveryStatus);
};

exports.onDataAdded = functions.database
  .ref("/messages/{messageId}")
  .onCreate(function(snap, context) {

    const createdData = snap.val();
    var name = createdData.name;
    var email = createdData.email;
    var number = createdData.number;
    var message = createdData.message;


    goMail(name, email, number, message);
  });
```

I'm not sure if my setup is wrong or if I'm doing something wrong with the nodemailer code in index.js.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: How do you trigger the function?

Comment: Really good question Frank, sorry to be such a noob but i am not so sure if i have performed the trigger, i was just looking at another example of doing this from the firebase team on github and did see a section about how they triggered the function based on the changes in the database, but in my own case i am somewhat lost. Would you be kind enough to point me in the right direction? Thank you.-----My database collects 4 different inputs in each collection that has a reference of "messages"

Comment: It sounds like you're pretty new to Cloud Functions, in which case taking a complex sample like the one you found and trying to make it work is probably a bit too much to do at once. The `onDataAdded` function triggers when a node node is created under `/emails`, and expects that new node to have an `email` property that is the message body you want to send to people.

Comment: You're correct indeed and you don't know how much i appreciate your input. ```var messageRef = firebase.database().ref("messages");``` is the collection reference in my database, from what you have explained to me so far, I think instead of ```exports.onDataAdded = functions.database
  .ref("/emails/{sessionId}")``` I need to have ```exports.onDataAdded = functions.database
  .ref("/messages/{sessionId}")```? Thanks again.

Comment: I'd recommend restarting for a moment, and following along with the Firebase documentation for Cloud Functions. First a simple [getting started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started), and then with [realtime database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events). These will help you better understand the code you copied, and should make you better prepared to modify it to your needs.

Comment: I will do just that. You have helped me more than i could ask for, I don't know how to thank you for your time. Cheers Frank!

Comment: In addition to Frank's recommendations, I would add that since your Cloud Function is triggered by a background event you must return a promise to indicate that the asynchronous tasks are finished. In your case it means that you should return the promise returned by `transporter.sendMail()` (Node Mailer will return a promise if no callback is given (https://nodemailer.com/usage/)). Returning a promise is key, as explained in the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thank you also for your input. Regarding the promises i was just watching the same videos you mentioned. After some reading and getting a better understanding of the functions i updated my index.js code. I would really appreciate it if you can have a look and give me feedback.

Comment: @Mike-Selles see the answer

Comment: Good catch Renaud!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the comment, since your Cloud Function is triggered by a background event, you must return a promise to indicate that the asynchronous tasks are finished.

So in the `goMail` function you should return the promise returned by the `sendMail()` method with:

```
...
return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);   //Remove the callback
```

And you should return, in the Cloud Function itself, the promise returned by the `goMail` function with:

```
return goMail(...)
```

Comment: Thank you Frank and Renaud you guys are super helpful. I got everything to work the way i wanted and learned on top.